# Scanning characters and integers at the same time

Tags: c++

I feel like an idiot, as Aconcagua solved my issue. I forgot the ampersand, and once I put it in there, the %s works for reading both char and int (something I didn't know)! Thanks all who offered help!

I have an input file for an assignment that has chemical formulas that need to be scanned in and printed (ex. SO). I am using a structure to read in the data as it is accompanied by a series of floating point numbers that are used in calculations. How would I declare the variable and scan that piece of data? I tried declaring as both char and unsigned char while using %s to try to read it in.

```
for(i = 0; i <= control - 1; i++)
{
    fscanf(table,"%s %lf %lf %lf %lf", gases[i].gas, gases[i].coefa,
           gases[i].coefb, gases[i].coefc, gases[i].coefd);
}
```

Input file:

```
4
12 6
SO2 3.891e1   3.904e-2   -3.105e-5   8.606e-9
SO3  4.85e1   9.188e-2   -8.540e-5   32.40e-9
O2   2.91e1   1.158e-2  -0.6076e-5   1.311e-9
N2   2.90e1  0.2199e-2  -0.5723e-5  -2.871e-9
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the input file.

Comment: Do you want all the 118 elements to be parsed? If so, the answer would become very broad... So you should consider telling us the limit...

Comment: Just a matter of style: With integers, `i <= n - 1`and `i < n` are equivalent, the latter reads easier, though...

Comment: Are you aware that you need to pass pointers to `scanf` function family? Assuming `coefX` members are doubles, you need to pass them as `&gases[i].coefX` (note the leading ampersand!).

Comment: You would want to declare a `struct` (or you could build a full `class`) with data members of `string` and 4-`double` values. You can then declare a `vector` of `struct` to hold all compounds and values.

Comment: Thats still no [mcve]. What is gases? And what are the three integers in the first two lines of the file?

Comment: One point about the character string: if `gases[i].gas` is a single character, the ampersand is fine. If it is an array (`char gas[SomeLimit];`, though, it is *wrong*: Arrays are passed as pointers to their first element (so e. g. `int[SomeLimit]]` is passed as `int*`) and they decay to automatically if passed to functions (and in some other cases). If you apply the addressof operator (the ampersand), you get a pointer, too, but of a totally different type: `int(*)[SomeLimit]` - ugly syntax, I know. Type 'is pointer to array of specific length'.

Comment: It *appeared* to work nicely - this is because the whole array and its first element share the same address - still it is (according to the standard) undefined behaviour because you pass pointers of bad type (`char*` is required, not `char(*)[X]`).

Comment: Back to '[...] is a single character, the ampersand is fine.': 'Fine' applies *only* for getting the correct type! '%s' format specifier will null-terminate the string, so using `%s` will write beyound the array bounds (single character can and needs to be considered as array of length 1 in this respect) - undefined behaviour again.

Answer (score 0):

In  general, in C++  you shouldn't be using `fscanf()`. You should be using file streams. So your example would  probably look something like this:

```
ifstream inputFile("path to input file");
//... other code
for (i = 0; i <= control -  1; i++)
{
    inputFile >> gases[i].gas;
    inputFile >> gases[i].coefa;
    inputFile >> gases[i].coefb;
    inputFile >> gases[i].coefc;
    inputFile >> gases[i].coefd;
}
```

This should  get  the proper types if you've declared the various members of whatever type `gases` is to be the same types as the data in the file. In  this case, it looks like `gas` would be a `std::string`, and the coefficients would be either `float` or `double`.

Comment: I can't say that I understand how most of that works. I'm in a basic programing class. I think I understand that first line, but we are still using #define and FILE *XXXXX for declaring input files. Is there anyway to use a fscanf?

Comment: @Tim - if you are bewildered by the above code, you need to go work through [C++ Tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html) or a similar one to understand the basics. It will take a couple of hours, but will save you untold amounts of time going forward. `fscanf` is a C function (callable in C++), but the reason we have C++ was to get away from calls like `fscanf`...